# Issue with finding height of slick slider container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

Having an issue with trying to get the height of the container for a slick slider that shows after clicking a title box.

I'm trying to capture the height and use that height to move the other title boxes the correct amount down, but it's capturing the height of the three slides before they condense into a slick slider, so its throwing off my layout. My container is ending up ~3x too tall since there are 3 slides and it pushes the other title boxes way too far down.

This is driving me nuts. Any help?

https://codepen.io/Finches/pen/vpZqYR

```
// Show/hide content from clicking box title
$('.track-box-title').click(function() {
  //Get height of content
  var height = $(this).parent('.track-box').parent('.track-box-container').find('.track-content').height() + 250;

  console.log(height);

  //Convert height to string
  var heightStr = height.toString();

  //Toggle height and content box display
  if ($(this).parent('.track-box').parent('.track-box-container').height() == 200) {
      $(this).parent('.track-box').parent('.track-box-container').animate({height: heightStr});
      $(this).parent('.track-box').parent('.track-box-container').find('.track-content').show();
      // initialize slick slider
      $(this).siblings('.track-content').find('.project-image-slider').slick({});
    }
    else if ($(this).parent('.track-box').parent('.track-box-container').height() == height) {
      $(this).parent('.track-box').parent('.track-box-container').find('.track-content').hide();
      $(this).parent('.track-box').parent('.track-box-container').animate({height: "200px"});
      $(this).siblings('.track-content').find('.project-image-slider').hide();
    }

});

$('.close-btn').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.content').parent('.track-content').hide();
  $(this).parent('.content').parent('.track-content').parent('.track-box').parent('.track-box-container').animate({height: "200px"});
});
```

Comment: Fixed this by setting the initial display on all slides to none except for the first slide.

Answer (score 1):

When the slick slider is properly loaded the class "slick-initialized" gets added.

You should use this in your JS selector and it should then get the correct height.

Comment: I tried incorporating this but was getting "null" as my height. It's because I'm not showing the parent container until after I get my heights I think. Any ideas on how to workaround this without messing up the slick slider?

Comment: Fixed this by setting the initial display on all slides to none except for the first slide.